# How to disable Eclipse auto-indent for multi-line annotations

Tags: eclipse, annotations, indentation, multiline, autoformatting

I have setup my Eclipse Luna to use the default auto formatting rules, except that I checked the "Enable Off/On tags" checkbox.  I kept the Off tag and On tag fields set to "@formatter:off" and "@formatter:on" respectively.

I have some multi-line annotations like this:

```
//@formatter:off
...
@ApiOperation(position = 10,
   value = "A Value",
   notes = "A lengthy description")
...
//@formatter:on
```

When I save the file, Eclipse formats this to:

```
//@formatter:off
...
@ApiOperation(position = 10,
value = "A Value",
notes = "A lengthy description")
...
//@formatter:on
```

With respect to the indentation, Eclipse Luna does not seem to respect the fact that I used the on/off tags.  Note that the on/off tags are working properly for everything else.

Is there a way to make Eclipse not adjust the auto-indentation in this manner?